# Tkinter Listbox: manipulate display of rows (or display one column but `curselection` another from same dataframe)

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am currently displaying in a `Listbox` a column of a pandas DataFrame which contains the `full path` of some files I need to work on. Right now it all works fine because I am displaying the full path in the Listbox, so that in my `on_select` I get the full path as `current_selection_text` and I can work on this item at my will.

```py
def on_select(event,**kwargs):
    # display element selected on list
    current_selection_text=event.widget.get(event.widget.curselection())
```

Full path is quite long usually so I want to not display it and display just the filename, still being able to select the full path without displaying the full path because it's just clutter.

My question is if there is a way to display the filename in the Listbox and at the same time selecting the corresponding full path.  The only way ahead that I see to achieve is:

- Listbox could provide functionality to display a function of the list that I have filled it with. To  be concrete I fill it by  `my_listbox.inset(end, x)` but then in the GUI I want to see `f(x)`. As there seems to be no control on how the items are displayed in Listbox I am unable to proceed (to be precise: [the official doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tkinter.ttk.html?highlight=listbox) has no mention of Listbox, and the [best reference I found](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_listbox.htm) says nothing about manipulating the display of the Listbox.

In alternative I thought of trying to display the DataFrame itself (or a subset of the columns) via [pandastable](https://pandastable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/description.html) instead of a Listbox. At that point I might select the row(s) I need and apply the functions I need. This seems quite a bigger gun to solve this problem, plus I never used pandastable so  I might not see roadblocks ahead. Suggestions are very welcome (if necessary I am willing to try other GUI makers such as pyQT).

Comment: There isn't any direct way to display just the filename and select it as a full path. One hack is to store the filenames in a dictionary and map it to the full paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct support, but it's trivial to keep a list of full paths synchronized with the list of filenames.

```
import tkinter as tk
from pathlib import Path

paths = [
    "/tmp/foo.py",
    "/tmp/bar.py",
    "/user/somebody/baz.py",
]

def get_selected_path(event):
    listbox = event.widget
    selection = listbox.curselection()
    if selection:
        index = selection[0]
        full_path = paths[index]
        label.configure(text=full_path)

root = tk.Tk()
listbox = tk.Listbox(root)
label = tk.Label(root, anchor="w")

label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
listbox.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

listbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", get_selected_path)
for path in paths:
    name = Path(path).name
    listbox.insert("end", name)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. Your code uses `curselection` and you get a `list`, whose first item is the index. That index is the key of your workaround. My code uses `curselection` as well, but I am getting a `string`, which is far less useful in this context. Can you point documentation where I can learn why we are getting two different things from seemingly the same function? I only found tutorials around and they have limitations if you need to do something slightly different.

Comment: On a similar note, I see that you pass just `event` as I did, but you then have to resort to a variable `listbox` that is defined at a different scope. Python allows for such things, but I wanted this `on_select` function to be a "parametric" functions, that is valid for a generic listbox. To that end I was obtaining the widget by `event.widget`. I checked now that I obtain this list also by `selection = event.widget.curselection()`.

Comment: I would like to stress again that I am recollecting al this from tutorials and SO answers (many of which are @Bryan Oakley, thanks a lot). This time I have searched specifically for `event.widget.curselection`, maybe when I wrote that part I stumbled on one that used `event.widget.get`. Again, where can I see these functions documented and presented fully?

Comment: Currenlty I have to work out how this way of working around can fit with the dynamic population of the listbox that I had coded. Basically I had an `Entry` which provided some text to be searched in the filenames and display only the matching files. This was not part of the original question so I am gladly accepting this answer. Thanks.